# Why Highlighting does not work on a Query results?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have a query like "+(+Contents:"risk factors" +Contents:"item 503" +Contents:concise) +(DocID:2548093)" it filters result but highlighting not works on the result of the query..
I tried to use all highlighters available in solr by appending hl.usefastvectorhighlighter 
but still highlighting does not works.. can any one help me on this.

Comment: Is this question about Solr or SolrNet? Can you make highlighting work on the Solr admin console? What does "does not work" mean (more concretely)? What fieldType is `Contents`?

Comment: Contents is of type text and it is not highlighting in both admin screen as well as in Solrnet..

Comment: can you make highlighting work with *any* query at all? can you post a sample full Solr URL (including query, highlighting parameters, etc)?

Comment: ya it works really good on other queries and here is complete url
http://localhost:8983/solr2/select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=%2B%28%2BContents%3A%22risk+factors%22+%2BContents%3A%22item+503%22+%2BContents%3Aconcise%29+%2B%28DocID%3A2548093%29+&fq=&start=0&rows=10&fl=*%2Cscore&qt=standard&wt=standard&explainOther=&hl=on&hl.fl=Contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can fix this by increasing hl.maxAnalyzedChars its default value is 51200. I have increased it 100000 and it is working fine now.

Comment: So in solrconfig.xml, you simply added <int name="hl.maxAnalyzedChars">1000000</int> in the Highlighting section?

Comment: no we dont need to add this in solrconfig.xml, you need to append this attribute in your request.